# Is it necessary to take a backup of the system_schema keyspace?

Tags: cassandra, backup, restore

I was wondering about the necessity to backup (in order to restore of course) the system keyspaces of Cassandra.

My backup/restore procedure is the following:

- backup: snapshots (nodetool) + dump of keyspaces (cqlsh DESC keyspace) on all cluster nodes
- restore:

  - create keyspaces (cqlsh)
  - restore schema.cql of all tables of all snapshots (cqlsh)
  - import tables of all snapshots (sstableloader)

With this procedure, I was wondering:

1. I read that among system keyspaces, only system_schema could be usefull to be backuped/restored, are there others ?
2. Since I recreate keyspaces, and reimport tables schema (cql included in snapshots for each table), is the backup/restore of the keyspace system_schema necessary ?

Thank you

Comment: friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

No, not necessary.  Maybe consider exporting the tables in the `system_auth` keyspace if you want to be able to recover your user data. But as long as you have that and your table CQL, there's nothing else you need to save or backup in the system keyspaces.  The node will replace/rebuild all of that at startup time, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you would never perform a restore of system keyspaces from a backup.

There are keyspaces such as `system` and `system_schema` which contain information that is unique to a node and is not relevant if you rebuild a node. In any case, you need to recreate the schema prior to restoring a snapshot so it is a moot point.

In the event that you need to "restore" a dead node, the first thing you would  do is install Cassandra which will then automatically create the system keyspaces for you.

The only exception to this might be the `system_auth` keyspace which contains roles and permissions. But given that the data in this keyspace is very small, it would be quicker to simply synchronise the data from replicas by running `nodetool repair` on the keyspace. Cheers!